# Airflow Bigquery Hook : how to save results in python variable?

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery, airflow, hook

I am using bigquery hook in my airflow code.

Query example : `select count(*) from 'table-name';`
so it will return only 1 integer as a result.

How can I save it in an Integer python variable instead of entire pandas dataframe ?

Below is my code example,

```
hook = BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id=BQ_CON, use_legacy_sql=False)
bq_client = bigquery.Client(project = hook._get_field("project"), credentials = hook._get_credentials())
query = "select count(*) from dataset1.table1;"
df = bq_client.query(query).to_dataframe()
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is just a single row, you could name the column `col1` and access it by this key name

```
query = "select count(*) as col1 from dataset1.table1;"

query_result = client.query(query)

result = query_result[0]['col1']
```

or if you have already called `to_dataframe()`

```
result = int(df.values[0])
```

Comment: Thanks ! i knew i was missing something very basic :)